# Proof that every $T_0$ Topological Vector Space is regular

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, separation-axioms

I'm currently reading through Convex Analysis and Beyond by Mordukhovich and Nam where the following preposition and proof are given (note that the authors define TVSs to be $T_0$).

> **Proposition 1.92** Let $X$ be a topological vector space $X$. Then $X$ is regular/$T_3$  while being, in particular, a Hausdorff topological space.
> *Proof.* It suffices to show that for any closed set $F ⊂ X$ and $x ∉ F$, there  exists an open neighborhood $V$ of the origin such that  $(x + V) ∩ (F + V) = ∅$.  Since $x ∈ F^c$ for the open complement $F^c$, we find a balanced open neighborhood $U$ of the origin with $x + U ⊂ F^c$. Then there exists a balanced open neighborhood $V$ of the origin such that $x + V + V ⊂ F^c$.  **It easily follows from the symmetry of $U$ that $(x + V) ∩ (F + V) = ∅$**,  which therefore verifies the statements of the proposition.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the part in bold. What does the syymmetry of $U$ have to do with the two sums being disjoint?

Comment: I suppose that, when you wrote $x\in F$, what you meant was $x\notin F$.

Comment: It surely should be the symmetry of $V$. If there is a point $y \in (x + V) \cap (F + V)$, then $y = x + v_1 = f + v_2$ for some $v_1, v_2 \in V$ and $f \in F$. So, $f = x + v_1 + (-v_2)$. Since $v_2 \in V$ and $V$ is balanced, $-v_2 \in V$, so $f \in (x + V + V) \cap F$, contradicting $x + V + V \subset F^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $z \in (x+V)\cap (F+V)$. Then, $z=x+v=f+v'$ with $v,v' \in V, f \in F$. Now, $-v'\in V$, so  $f=x+v+(-v')\in x+V+V \subset F^{c}$, a contradiction.